# How to Sort the rows in Ms-Access Table using only 1 row?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to sort one of my tables in my database ms-access using only 1 column.
the value of the column is like this:

```
PartMaterial
---------------------
C90X61Y13B
C90X61Y13D
C90X61Y1B
--------------------
```

I did not put all the data in here because it's too many.

but i tried this sql:

```
SELECT DISTINCT PartMaterial FROM tblMaterialMark ORDER BY PartMaterial ASC
```

but the result is like this:

```
PartMaterial
---------------------
C90X61Y13B
C90X61Y13D
C90X61Y1B
--------------------
```

which is wrong, because `C90X61Y1B` should be the first in line.

Correct output:

```
PartMaterial
---------------------
C90X61Y1B
C90X61Y13B
C90X61Y13D
--------------------
```

How can I possibly sort these items in ascending order with the integer and string combined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is alphabetical.  Perhaps you want by length:

```
ORDER BY LEN(PartMaterial),  PartMaterial
```

If this doesn't work with `SELECT DISTINCT`, you can try `GROUP BY` instead:

```
SELECT PartMaterial
FROM tblMaterialMark 
GROUP BY PartMaterial
ORDER BY LEN(PartMaterial),  PartMaterial
```

Comment: how to do that with the `DISTINCT` sir?